# Looking for information about pathfinding on isometric maps

Tags: javascript, dom, performance, path-finding

I am working on a game engine called Engine1 (logo is a big steam train). I've been very successful with motion animation, sprite animation and element manipulation. I can create/destory/animate elements very quickly (about ~1000 elements every 1/40 of a second).

I'm now **looking to expand my engine** to include a library for **isometric maps with path finding** support.
Please don't give me copy and paste code. I'm **looking for information and theory about efficient algorithms for isometric path-finding**.

I also plan on releasing my engine as open source after I release my own game with it first (proof of concept). If your interested in snagging an early build message me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic grid path-finding algorithm is very simple:

- Take your starting cell, recursively hit every adjacent possible cell

  - ignore invalid cells, e.g. walls/etc
- whenever you hit a cell, ***only*** continue if you're at the lowest step for that cell.  e.g.:
- Die whenever you're further than the best distance so far

  ```
  A B C
  D E F
  G H I
  ```

You have several paths from A-I (in random order):

- A-B(1)-C(2)-F(3)-E(4)-H(5)-I(6)
- A-D(1)-E(2)-B(3) -- die because B(3) > B(1)
- A-D(1)-E(2)-F(3)-I(4)
- A-B(1)-E(2)-D(3) -- die because D(3) > D(1)